# Retrieve all domains information Google Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I would like to retrieve all domain information that are added to Domains section in Admin panel. 
In short I require an API that returns the info. displayed here : https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#Domains:

I've already gone thru Admin SDK's Directory API as well as Admin Settings API but I don't find anything there.

I have been searching for long but I don't fine anything useful. There are 2 questions in stackoverflow as well but that doesn't answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this information is available today via the APIs in the Admin SDK.